# How to start steam on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: steam, 18.04, multiverse

I installed steam through the multiverse repository. Yet when trying to start it the client won't show. On first start, it will update steam, yet once that finished no steam client will pop up and each start of steam will result in direct exit.

When running from terminal, it will log:

```
$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 18.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
[2018-05-14 20:29:27] Startup - updater built Apr  2 2018 15:23:43
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2018-05-14 20:29:27] Checking for update on startup
[2018-05-14 20:29:27] Checking for available updates...
[2018-05-14 20:29:27] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1522709999, installed version 1522709999
[2018-05-14 20:29:27] Nothing to do
[2018-05-14 20:29:27] Verifying installation...
[2018-05-14 20:29:27] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2018-05-14 20:29:28] Verification complete
```

I find it confusing that no apparent error seems to be logged.

I both removed my `~/.steam/steam/appcache` at first, and then I purged my entire `~/.steam/` folder to no avail.

It was working fine when running 16.04.

How can I start the steam client?

Comment: try `LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/$LIB/libgcc_s.so.1 /usr/$LIB/libxcb.so.1 /usr/$LIB/libgpg-error.so' /usr/bin/steam` if it helps I'll write a proper answer

Comment: @SkanderBejaoui That doesn't work. My path to steam is also `/usr/games/steam`

Comment: had similar/same problem since Bionic Beta, and fixed it that way. I'll leave the source [here](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/4816#issuecomment-339329851) for anyone to check. Also, I believe `/usr/bin/steam` is the updater while `/usr/bin/steam` is the actual client. I'm sorry I couldn't help